# specify different xlim for each plot in facet_wrap (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

that's my code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, EC))+
  scale_x_date(labels= date_format("%Y"), breaks=date_breaks("year"))+
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(Date, EC), size=2, color="red")+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  xlab(NULL)+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F)+
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales="free_y")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

That produce this result (I know it's ugly, but take it just as an example):
[image]

Can I specify different xlim (base on date values) for each plot in facet_wrap? It would be great if I can specify xlim based on the min(df$Date).

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Why don't you just use `scales = "free"` in `facet_wrap()` to free both the `x` and `y` scales?

Comment: Yes, it could be a chance..

Comment: This question still not be resolved. Although `scales = "free"` was used, there still several points locate at the margin position. Especially when you add text to the points, the text will only be showed partly. Any suggestions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This should be solved. Trying on some wide ranged data:

```
data <- data.frame( grp=rep(c("one","two","three","four"), each=10),
                    x=1:40,
                    y=c( runif(10)*3,
                       ( runif(10)*30 )+10,
                       ( runif(10)*50 )+10,
                       ( runif(10)*10 )-10 ) )

ggplot( data, aes(x, y) ) +
              geom_point(  ) +
              geom_line( ) +
              geom_smooth( method = "loess" ) +
              facet_wrap( ~grp, scales="free" )
```

[image: ggplot_facet_wrap_scale]